# How to redirect a specific user after log-in?

Tags: users, wp-redirect

I want to redirect an user and his user ID is 6. So I added this code into my `functions.php`

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
      if ($user_id == 6) {
            /* redirect users to front page after login */
            function redirect_to_front_page() {
                global $redirect_to;
                    if (!isset($_GET['redirect_to'])) {
                    $redirect_to = get_option('siteurl');
                    }
                }
            add_action('login_form', 'redirect_to_front_page');             
      }
    }
```

But still the user goes to the rpofile page after the log-in. How can I get it works?

**[update]**
Then I've tried to change to username instead of user ID but still same. He gets profile page after login. 
like this:

```
function redirect_to_front_page() {
    global $redirect_to;
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        //$user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

          //if ($user_id == 6) 
          if ($current_user->user_login = 'hirer') {
            /* redirect users to front page after login */
            if (!isset($_GET['redirect_to'])) {
                $redirect_to = get_option('siteurl');
            }
        }

    }
}
add_action('login_redirect', 'redirect_to_front_page');
```

still nothing changed. The user gets profile page when he login.

Comment: it looks like your hook(`login_form`) is wrong.

Comment: What profile page are you talking about?

Comment: @cybmeta this page: www.mysite.com/wp-admin/profile.php

Comment: And where do you want ot redirect the user?

Comment: @cybmeta to `www.mysite.com`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the `login_redirect` filter **returning** the redirect location:

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'redirect_to_home', 10, 3 );
function redirect_to_home( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {

    if( $user->ID == 6 ) {
        //If user ID is 6, redirect to home
        return get_home_url();
    } else {
        //If user ID is not 6, leave WordPress handle the redirection as usual
        return $redirect_to;
    }

}
```

Comment: works like a charm.. thanks a lot.. any why my code doesn't work. Probably that code also should work. right?

Comment: You was not **returning** the redirect location and you was trying to redirect only if `$_GET['redirect_to']` is not set and `$_GET['redirect_to']` is always set unless you access directly to the login form.

Answer (score 1):

use `login_redirect` hook instead `login_form`
And you can move conditions inside your function

like below code.

```
function redirect_to_front_page() {
    global $redirect_to;
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
          if ($user_id == 6) {
            /* redirect users to front page after login */
            if (!isset($_GET['redirect_to'])) {
                return $redirect_to = get_option('siteurl');
            }
        }

    }
}
add_action('login_redirect', 'redirect_to_front_page' , 10 , 3 );
```

Comment: thanks for that. but nothing happened still the user gets profile page after login. I've tried to change to username instead of user ID but still same. He gets profile page after login. check my updated codes.

Comment: may be it's because you have another plugin that's overriding `login_redirect` action.

Comment: check updated code.